# why installing docker on rhel 8 make conflicts with runc

Tags: docker, rpm, yum, rhel8

we want to install docker packages on our **RHEL 8.4** server (this is off line installation since machine not connected to network)

so we download the following rpm's from the site - https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/8/x86_64/stable/Packages/

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34558068 Sep  6 14:41 containerd.io-1.6.9-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3930488 Sep  6 14:42 docker-scan-plugin-0.9.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13710120 Sep  6 14:42 docker-buildx-plugin-0.11.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25375804 Sep  6 14:42 docker-ce-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7514336 Sep  6 14:43 docker-ce-cli-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5119608 Sep  6 14:43 docker-ce-rootless-extras-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7370924 Sep  6 14:43 docker-compose-plugin-2.6.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

then we tried to install the rpm's with `yum localinstall`  but we get the following exception

```
Error:
 Problem: package containerd.io-1.6.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module+el8.4.0+10607+f4da7515.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.6.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module+el8.4.0+10607+f4da7515.x86_64
  - package buildah-1.19.7-1.module+el8.4.0+10607+f4da7515.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package buildah-1.19.7-1.module+el8.4.0+10607+f4da7515.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

one of exception above is complain about - `requires runc >= 1.0.0-26`

but when we check the runc rpm version we get:

```
rpm -qa | grep runc
runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module+el8.4.0+10607+f4da7515.x86_64
```

so I not understand why yum complained about version runc-1.0.0-70 and other exceptions

any suggestion to solve this problem? and what is the right approach to install the rpm on rhel 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this problem because you have installed `runc` which provide the functionality to run containers. Just use `podman` to run containers.

Or deinstall `podman`, `runc` and then install `docker`.

Answer (score 1):

Docker has detailed steps for installing on RHEL/CentOS that it looks like you've skipped: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

It looks like you have multiple competing installations of the tools and you need to pick one. I don't believe installing buildah/podman in addition to docker will be supported.